# Android registration and login using soap web service

Tags: android, soap

can any one help me to write code for registration page using SOAP web service.i developing an patients checking app in which first user have to register . plz help me anyone have any idea about this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Ksoap2` to send data to your webservice and log your user. here a beginner tutorial about getting data from webservice using this library (to understands the basics) [communicate between asp net webservice an android app using ksoap2](http://programmertoolbox.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/communicate-between-asp-net-webservice-and-android-app/)

Comment: any one have any tutorial for registration page using SOAP web service

Comment: this question may help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208875/how-to-create-login-page-in-android-use-ksoap2-web-service-sharepoint)

Comment: your link is not useful for me.it got error.if u have any another link,then let me know.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
          SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);        

        request.addProperty("userFirstname",sFirstName);
        request.addProperty("userLastname",sLastName);
        request.addProperty("dob",sBOD );
        request.addProperty("gender",spinnersex.getSelectedItem().toString());
        request.addProperty("address",sAddress);
        request.addProperty("city",sCity);
        request.addProperty("state", sState);
        request.addProperty("pincode",sAreaCode);
        request.addProperty("mobile",sPhoneNo );
        request.addProperty("mailid",sEmailId );
        request.addProperty("bg",spinnerBloodgroup.getSelectedItem().toString());
       // request.addProperty("date",Date.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("weight",sweight); 

        //Declare the version of the SOAP request
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);     
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        try {

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
             androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);
            Log.e("ressult","data"+ re);

        SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();  
            Log.e("value of result", " result"+result);
            if(result!= null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successfully register ", 2000).show()  ;
            }
            else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Try Again..", 2000).show() ;   
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
```

> I think  your problem will be solve with this code otherwise i give you briefly
>   description